# NameError: name '__main__' is not defined

Tags: python, program-entry-point, maya

I have been reading here, but I couldnt find any solution online to solve my problem..I think I have the indentation right, but I still get the Name Error..Can someone help me out please. 
This script should run a new panel in maya, which works kind of, but the error is really annoying.

```
class PanelWindow( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, title, namespace=__name__ ):
        self.__name__ = name
        self._title = title
        self.instance = str(namespace) + '.' + self.__name__

        if not pm.scriptedPanelType(self.__name__, q = True, ex = True):
            pm.scriptedPanelType(self.__name__, u = True)

        jobCmd = 'python(\\\"%s._setup()\\\")' % self.instance
        job = "scriptJob -replacePrevious -parent \"%s\" -event \"SceneOpened\" \"%s\";" % ( self.__name__, jobCmd )
        mel.eval(job)

        pm.scriptedPanelType( self.__name__, e = True,
                       unique=True,
                       createCallback = 'python("%s._createCallback()")' % self.instance,
                       initCallback = 'python("%s._initCallback()"  )' % self.instance,
                       addCallback = 'python("%s._addCallback()"   )' % self.instance,
                       removeCallback = 'python("%s._removeCallback()")' % self.instance,
                       deleteCallback = 'python("%s._deleteCallback()")' % self.instance,
                       saveStateCallback = 'python("%s._deleteCallback()")' % self.instance
                        )


    def _setup(self):
        """Command to be call for new scene"""
        panelName = pm.sceneUIReplacement( getNextScriptedPanel=(self.__name__, self._title) )
        if panelName == '':
            try:
                panelName = pm.scriptedPanel( mbv=1, unParent=True, type=self.__name__, label=self._title )
            except:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                label = panel( self.__name__, query=True, label=True )
                pm.scriptedPanel( self.__name__, edit=True,  label=self._title )
            except:
                pass
    def _addCallback(self):
        """Create UI and parent any editors."""
        print 'ADD CALLBACK'
    def show( self ):        
        mel.eval('tearOffPanel "%s" %s true;' % (self._title, self.__name__) )


global test
test = PanelWindow('myName', 'Light')

test.show()


# NameError: name '__main__' is not defined # 
# Error: line 1: name '__main__' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# NameError: name '__main__' is not defined #
```

Comment: Your code has no `__main__` in it. Show us the actual code that gives this error

Comment: it looks like your using some non-standard python console (maya-console) ... that is probably the problem ... I would check on their forums

Comment: … and please post a **minimal** code which exhibits this problem. 99% of your code is irrelevant here.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, maya has a built in script editor and python interpreter. `__main__` still had to be in the code somewhere.

Comment: (it might be in some wrapper they use or something) ...

Comment: as someone who uses maya every working day, i assure you it's not.

Comment: heh there we go :P (I hadnt used it :P) I know the program I work on has a built in shell and we definitely do some magic in it :P

Comment: This is the entire code. I can assure you that.

Comment: This is not the entire code, you're missing some.

Comment: To start with, you're definitely missing `import maya.cmds as pm`

Comment: @ShannonHochkins, maya remembers that if you've done it in the script editor before and have copy/pasted this new script in

Comment: I am using mayas interpreter, where I have a user setup, where import maya.cmds as cmds, import pymel.core as pm and import maya.mel as mel are imported

Comment: Some people may not know that @mhlester

Comment: that is true; my point is this may be the full code OP is pasting in, despite the missing import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem was a few things, I've only included a few basic sections of the code as the rest wasn't needed.

Problem one was `__name__`, if this were quoted, we wouldn't have a problem, seeing as it's just a name and not anything special, I'm just going to rename this to `name`.

Problem two was duplicate names on panels/panelTypes. IE:

```
pm.scriptedPanelType(self.__name__, u = True)
pm.scriptedPanel( self.__name__, edit=True,  label=self._title )
```

Maya didn't like that both the panelType and the panel had the same names.

So:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.mel as mel

class PanelWindow( object ):
    def __init__(self, name, title):

        self._name = name
        self._title = title
        self.panelTypeName = self._name + "Type"



        if not pm.scriptedPanelType(self.panelTypeName, query=True, exists=True):
            pm.scriptedPanelType(self.panelTypeName, unique=True)

        if not pm.scriptedPanel(self._title, query=True, exists=True):
            ## Only allows one instance
            pm.scriptedPanel(self._title, menuBarVisible=1, unParent=True, type=self.panelTypeName, label=self._title )

    def _addCallback(self):
        """Create UI and parent any editors."""
        print 'ADD CALLBACK'        


    def show( self ):  
        mel.eval('tearOffPanel "%s" "%s" true;' % (self._title, self._name) )  



PanelWindow('lightControlType1', 'lightControl').show()
```

Comment: While it seems pointless to call `str` on `namespace`, it's extremely unlikely that this has anything to do with the error.

Comment: It removes the __main__ error, now I get:
# Error: 'PanelWindow' object has no attribute 'name'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 50, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 9, in __init__
# AttributeError: 'PanelWindow' object has no attribute 'name' #

Comment: ...or perhaps I'm missing something. I'm inclined to think the difference is due to something unrelated to this change, such as turning the interpreter off and on again, but downvote tentatively removed.

Comment: What version of Maya are you running @arvidurs?

Comment: Hm weird, I closed it now several times..Still get the error. I ll try again. Thanks anyways for your effort!

Comment: also testing on maya 2014

Comment: Could you contact me on skype please: arvidurs

Comment: Yes if I call it like this PanelWindow('myName', 'Light') its fine. But when I want to use the tearoffpanel function, to create the window, I get the error again.
Like this:

PanelWindow('myName', 'Light').show()

Comment: To start with, it might help if you provide us with what you're actually attempting to do, I'm going to clean up this conversation as it's getting too extensive. Please edit your original question, with what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 17):

When executing Python scripts, the Python interpreter sets a variable called `__name__` to be the string value `"__main__"` for the module being executed (normally this variable contains the module name).

It is common to check the value of this variable to see if your module is being imported for use as a library, or if it is being executed directly. So you often see this block of code at the end of modules:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do stuff
```

I suspect you have left the string quotes off of `'__main__'` which gives the NameError you're seeing

```
>>> if __name__ == __main__:
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__main__' is not defined
```